# df.plot not overlaying exactly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am using df.plot(kind='hist') to graph some data I have. I am graphing two sets of histograms and overlaying them on top of each other to visualize the difference between two groups. The problem I have is that both sets of histograms are not lieing exactly on top of each other (bins seems to be offset very slightly).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.plot(kind='hist', x='var1', bins=20)
df.plot(kind='hist', y='var2', bins=20)
plt.show()
```

Here is an image that I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlKmc.jpg

Comment: Obviously if you want to have both histograms to use the same bins, you need to actually use the same bins. E.g. `bins = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), 20)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
df[['var1','var2']].plot(kind='hist', bins=20, alpha=.5)
```